# How to use CHECK_LIBRARY_EXISTS in cmake?

Tags: linux, cmake, embedded-linux

Here’s what I have in my CMakeLists.txt:

```
link_directories( "/usr/local/lib" )
include(CheckLibraryExists)
CHECK_LIBRARY_EXISTS( "libmali-midgard-t76x-r9p0-r0p0.so" "gbm_create_device" "" MALI )
```

Result:

```
Looking for gbm_create_device in libmali-midgard-t76x-r9p0-r0p0.so - not found
```

The symbol exists in that library:

```
$ nm -D /usr/local/lib/libmali-midgard-t76x-r9p0-r0p0.so | egrep gbm_create_device
001b245c T gbm_create_device
```

Why cmake doesn't find that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was dependencies.

`CHECK_LIBRARY_EXISTS` is much more complex than `nm -D`. CMake actually creates a C project that references that library, and tries to link it.

I missed some dependencies used by that library (libdrm-dev, libxcb-dri2-0, libx11-xcb-dev), so the linker failed.

Resolved by looking what’s in CMakeFiles folder, it contains much more detailed logs.